# Enviar imagen grande a API visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Tengo esta api en visual basic que me recibe la cadena de base64 de una imagen pero al momento de enviarle una image de 5mb me aparece el error de "No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo System.NullReferenceException al tipo Entidades.Excepcion.,", esto solo me sucede cuando intento enviar imagenes de gran tamaño, pero cuando envio imagenes pequeñas si funciona, que puede ser y como lo puedo resolver?

esto es lo que tengo en mi controlador en mi api:

```
        <HttpPost>
        <Route("api/remito/ingresar")>
        Public Function ingresarremito(ByVal remito As DTO.RemitoEDTO) As IHttpActionResult

            Try
                Dim remitoDTO As String = RemitoFunciones.registrarremitosconfoto(remito.vac_id, remito.vac_remito_id, remito.vac_fecha, remito.vac_proveedor_id, remito.vac_combustible_id, remito.vac_litros, remito.vac_monto, remito.vac_imagen)
                Return Ok(remitoDTO)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return devolverExcepcion(ex)
            End Try
        End Function
```

esto es lo que tengo en RemitoEDTO:

```
Public Class RemitoEDTO
    Public Property vac_id As Int64
    Public Property vac_remito_id As Int64
    Public Property vac_fecha As String
    Public Property vac_combustible_id As Int64
    Public Property vac_proveedor_id As Int64
    Public Property vac_litros As Double
    Public Property vac_monto As Double
    Public Property vac_imagen As String

End Class
```

En esta imagen muestro el error que me da en postman, despues de la funcion del controlador ya no avanza simplemente me da ese error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tiene una pinta de que el problema real no se ve y que tienes líos con ese método devolverexcepción... pero no conozco casi nada de .net, así que no lo sé con certeza

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mirar de reducir el tamaño de la imagen a menos de 1MByte.

Una solución no muy ortodoxa (pero práctica) es ir dividiendo sucesivamente el ancho y alto por 2, 3, 4, ... y cada vez comprobar si ocupa menos de 1MB (= 1 millón de bytes = 10^6 bytes). Así, el código sería el siguiente:

```
Function ReducirImagenBase64(strImagenEnBase64 As String) As String
    Dim curImg As Image
    Try
        If strImagenEnBase64.Length < 10 ^ 6 Then
            Exit Try
        End If
        Dim BArray() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(strImagenEnBase64)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(BArray)
        curImg = Image.FromStream(ms)
        Dim w As Int32 = curImg.Width
        Dim h As Int32 = curImg.Height
        Dim tamañoDeLaImagen As Int32
        ' Empezamos dividiendo por dos:
        For div As Int32 = 2 To 10
            Dim tp As New Bitmap(curImg, CInt(w / div), CInt(h / div))
            Dim pic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(tp)
            pic.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bicubic
            pic.DrawImage(tp, 0, 0, Width, Height)
            curImg = tp
            Dim msR As New MemoryStream
            tp.Save(msR, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            BArray = msR.ToArray
            strImagenEnBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(BArray, 0, BArray.Length)
            tamañoDeLaImagen = strImagenEnBase64.Length
            If tamañoDeLaImagen < 10 ^ 6 Then
                Exit For ' si la imagen ocupa menos de 1 MByte -> fin del bucle
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return strImagenEnBase64
End Function
```